# Customizing Ag-grid header groups

Tags: angular, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

I need to customize header groups in Ag-grid (in Angular):
1) make text in them centered (it is left aligned by default);
2) make background of each header group particular color

How can that be done?

I tried to do that in SCSS for that class, but nothing changed on the view,
even when I renamed file it from SCSS to CSS.

Using Angular6, Ag-grid v.20, SCSS.

Please help!

TIA,
Oleg

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to center the header group text in ag-Grid, all you need to do is to use the `justify-content` CSS property on the `.ag-header-group-cell-label` class.

You might have to set this on your main styles.scss (the one which is on the same directory level as your index.html, package.json, etc)

```
.ag-header-group-cell-label {
  justify-content: center;
}
```

Likewise, this is how you can customise the colour of your header groups.

```
.ag-header-group-cell-with-group {
    background-color: blue;
}
```

Here is a [demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/mrwtOLFEM5aQJi5Rnuvs?p=preview) for your reference. I have made the changes on the styles.css file.

As for customising your own header groups, you should do it by writing your own custom [header group components](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-header-rendering/#header-group-component).

For instance, this is how you should define your columnDefs on your component that contains the ag-grid, whereby the header group is called "Personal", and the custom component is called `customHeaderGroupComponent`

```
this.columnDefs = [
  {
    headerName: "Personal",
    headerGroupComponent: "customHeaderGroupComponent",
    children: [
      {
        headerName: "Athlete",
        field: "athlete"
      },
      {
        headerName: "Age",
        field: "age"
      }]
  },
]
```

You can refer to the rest of the demo over [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ag-grid-header-groupheader-component-emoxkk?file=app/custom-headergroup.component.ts)

Comment: Hi Wentjun.  Both things work for me (suprisingly, from main scss file, not from mycomponent.scss.  One little change:  I wanted to show several header groups with their column headers in different colors (so users will see different groups immediately).  How can that be done?

Comment: Yes, that is because the way Angular's view encapsulation work. Regarding that header group customisation, you will need to extend it by defining your own `headerGroupComponent`, and defining your own CSS styles over there. I will write a brief outline of it, and you should can explore it on your own?

Comment: Thank you for this, small question, why  headerGroupComponent: "customHeaderGroupComponent", needs a special mention but not for CustomHeader. Even though both are provided in the frameworkcomponents? I tried giving the group header as agColumnHeaderGroup. But that did not take effect.

Answer (score 1):

To center your text, you need to manually customize the component in your CSS file like so:

```
    ::ng-deep .ag-header-cell-label {
      display: flex;
      justify-content:center;

      ::ng-deep .ag-header-cell-text {
        display:flex;
        align-items:center;
      }
    }
```

For your background color, you can do similar to the above, **just choose your class you want to modify** using the ::ng-deep.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

I needed to do this exact same thing, and I found that the other answers didn't fully answer the question for me. The documentation mostly talks about using a component for rendering, but that didn't work for me and I found it to be overkill for applying some simple styling. You have to define CSS styles for `ag-header-group-cell-with-group` - that is the main key. Otherwise styles will not show on your UI even though you specify a headerClass in your column definitions.  Here is how to do it in CSS:

```
::ng-deep .ag-header-group-cell-with-group {
    .ag-header-group-cell-label {
        justify-content: center;
    }
}

::ng-deep .ag-header-group-cell-with-group.blueFill {
    background-color: blue;
}

::ng-deep .ag-header-group-cell-with-group.redFill {
    background-color: red;
}
```

In your column definitions apply the styling like this:

```
{
    headerName: 'Parent Group A',
    headerClass: 'blueFill',
    children: [...]
},
{
    headerName: 'Parent Group B',
    headerClass: 'redFill',
    children: [...]
}
```